# Committing a transaction inside a nested transactionscope

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have the following scenario:

```
using (TransactionScope TX = new TransactionScope()) 
{

   for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
   {
      //Loop and perform DB updates.

      //Update logs
      using (TransactionScope TX1 = new TransactionScope()) 
      {
         //Open DB Connection and update the logs to say i out of iterations complete.
         TX1.Complete();
      }
   }

   TX.Complete();
}
```

The problem I have is I want to update the logs so the user can check to see progress but I don't want to commit the main block of SQL that is being performed in the loop.

Not sure if I am missing something obvious but does anyone have any suggestions.

I am using ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems that you would want to update your log inside of the FOR loop, not outside of it.

Secondly, you have two transactions with the same name.  Name your nested transaction something else (like TX_2 or something).

Comment: The code is a mock up of my scenario, not my actual code. I will adjust the example. Thanks.

Comment: OK -- so I see your edit.  Now...what's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: What I mean is...at what point do you WANT to commit the outer transaction?

Comment: I want to commit the log transaction `TX1` on each iteration through the loop but don't want to commit the other updates `TX` until they have all finished.

Comment: I see -- and that's not happening now?  From the look of your code, TX1 will commit on each iteration; TX will not commit until all iterations have finished.

Comment: It doesn't seem to update the database until `TX.Complete()` runs. I am assuming this is because it's a nested transaction.